# skip some empty rows in csv file and continue reading rows with data

Tags: c#, csv

I do have have 4 columns within my CVS file, the first two columns have 2 empty rows. I would like to skip these empty rows. I know that I have to loop through the file however I do not know how to do this process.

Any suggestions would be appreciate it.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Santander .csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        var target = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

As you can see in this image I would like the the commas at the beginning to be removed and only display rows who contains data inside the column.

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output? This is exactly like your previous question: [How to skip some empty rows in csv file and continue reading rows with data? c# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954395/how-to-skip-some-empty-rows-in-csv-file-and-continue-reading-rows-with-data-c-s#38954692)

Comment: data, data , data, data , data, data, data
 data, data, data
Store Number,Store Name, this is the desired output i would like

Comment: Do you want your output to be a collection of strings from all columns together in one list?

Comment: yes i would want that

Comment: There are some good answers below but I really like Streamreader for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the first character in the line is a `,`, if so you'll know that the first column is empty:

```
foreach (var line in fileContents)
{
    if(line.Trim().IndexOf(",") == 0)
    {
        // first column empty, skip
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: i do not wish to skip the full column but just the first two rows in each column1 and 2 as it is shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments and from previous question: you can use the `SelectMany` to get all your columns into separate items in your collection and then to filter out the empty ones:

```
public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
{
    File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(','))
        .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @user5813072 - Did this help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general you have to read csv file byte by byte to validate it and to read it correctly in case when some cells contain \n and ; inside of "

But for simple case you can use something like this:

```
foreach (var line in fileContents)
    {
        if (line.Split(',').Any(s => s == ""))
            continue;
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

And you also have one mistake in file reading function. It always returns empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get all the lines without empty data, then try this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lines = new string[3];

            string data1 = "data1,data2,data3,data4";
            string data2 = ",,data3,data4";
            string data3 = "data1,data2,data3,";

            lines[0] = data1;
            lines[1] = data2;
            lines[2] = data3;

            var result = lines
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                .Where(linePart => linePart.All(part => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part)))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

`result` will contains a list of `string[]` lines which did not contain any empty data parts.